# Approximation of partial sum over prime omega function

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic-functions

I asked the question in Math StackExchange. Link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4765476/approximation-of-partial-sum-over-prime-omega-function

I haven't got any response yet. Here are the details:

The prime omega function $\omega(n)$ counts the number of distinct prime factors of a natural number $n$, and can be defined as $\omega(n)=\sum_{p \mid n}1$. Let $S(N)=\sum_{n=1}^{N}n\omega(n)$. Let $\pi(n)$ denote the number of primes up to $n$.

$$\eqalign{S(N)
  &=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{\scriptstyle p{\text{ prime}} \atop \scriptstyle p\leq N} p\left(\left\lfloor\dfrac{N}{p}\right\rfloor ^2+\left\lfloor\dfrac{N}{p}\right\rfloor\right)\cr
  &\approx \dfrac{N\pi(N)}{2}+\dfrac{N^2}{2}\sum_{\scriptstyle p{\text{ prime}} \atop \scriptstyle p\leq N} \dfrac{1}{p}\cr
  &\approx \dfrac{N\pi(N)}{2}+\dfrac{N^2}{2}\left[\log \log N+M+o(1)\right],\cr}$$
where $M$ is the Meissel–Mertens constant.

The error term of this approximation is quite large. Is it possible to find a better approximation for this sum?

A better approximation for the sum of reciprocal primes (see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.08032.pdf) does not help to improve the overall sum.

The following approximation seems to work well.
$$\tilde{S}(N,\epsilon)=\left[\dfrac{N\pi(N)}{2}+\dfrac{N^2}{2}\left(\log \log N+M\right)\right]\cdot \left(1+\dfrac{1}{(\log N)^{1+\epsilon}}\right)^{-1}$$, where $\epsilon \in (0,1)$. Define the percentage error as $E(N,\epsilon)=\left |\dfrac{S(N)-\tilde{S}(N,\epsilon)}{S(N)}\right |\times 100$. The following table gives an idea as to how well the approximation works for $\epsilon=\dfrac{2}{5}$.

| $N$ | $S(N)$ | $E\left(N,\frac{2}{5}\right)$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $10^3$ | $1104960$ | $0.192894816907$ |
| $10^4$ | $124547620$ | $0.0961202670514$ |
| $10^5$ | $13558020500$ | $0.0234415251444$ |
| $10^6$ | $1446379298344$ | $0.00741488319826$ |
| $10^7$ | $152305298038685$ | $0.0118235266249$ |
| $10^8$ | $15895296473923817$ | $0.00880016331673$ |
| $10^9$ | $1648198262567978862$ | $0.00327960320611$ |
| $10^{10}$ | $170070011690546177056$ | $0.00270740071241$ |

Comment: Perhaps you can use the [Erdős–Kac theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Kac_theorem). If you treat $\omega(n)$ as a random variable with mean and variance $\log \log n$, you get a sum of normal variables with mean and variance $n \log \log n$, so the total sum is a normal variable with mean and variance $\sum_{i=1}^n {i \log \log i}$, so you'd expect the number to be around $\sum_{i=1}^n {i \log \log i} \pm \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n {i \log \log i}}$. This is mostly heuristic, I don't know if assuming these are independent can be justified

Comment: @CommandMaster Thanks! I was not aware of this theorem. I shall try to get a better estimate using this.

Comment: My comment is inaccurate, the variance is actually $i^2 \log \log i$, but it should still give an error term of $\tilde O(n^{1.5})$ if it is correct

Comment: @Charles there is another error term, since $\lfloor \frac n p \rfloor^2 = (\frac n p + O(1))^2 = (\frac n p)^2 + O(\frac n p)$

Comment: Assuming RH I can show this sum is $\frac12N^2\sum_{p\leq\sqrt N}\frac1p+\sum_{i\leq\sqrt N\\p\text{ prime}}{i (\text{li}(\frac{N^2}{i^2}) - \text{li}(N))}+O( N^{1.75 + \epsilon})$, but I'm not sure how to estimate the left part of the sum.

Comment: @CommandMaster, please see the edited question. The empirical approximation I came up with works very well. Not sure how to prove it or estimate the error term.

Answer (score 6):

By partial summation, one has
$$
S(N) = N\sum_{n=1}^N \omega(n) - \int_{1}^N \bigg(\sum_{n\leq t} \omega(n)\bigg) dt.
$$
Using Mertens' theorem with the classical error term in the prime number theorem, one has, for some constant $c > 0$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=1}^N \omega(n) = \sum_{p\leq N} \Big\lfloor \frac{N}{p}\Big\rfloor &= N \sum_{p\leq N} \frac{1}{p} - \sum_{p\leq N} \left\{ \frac{N}{p}\right\} \\
&= N \Big(\log\log N + M + O\Big(\exp\big(-c\sqrt{\log N}\big) \Big) \Big)- \sum_{p\leq N} \left\{ \frac{N}{p}\right\} 
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\{\cdot\}$ denotes the fractional part. The sum of fractional parts can evaluated using Proposition 3 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.0232.pdf), and we have
$$
\sum_{p\leq N} \left\{ \frac{N}{p}\right\} = \int_{2}^N \frac{\left\{N/t \right\}}{\log t} dt + O\Big(\exp\big(-c(\log N)^{3/5-\varepsilon}\big) \Big).
$$
By Proposition 2 of the above paper, the integral can be expanded asymptotically into a sum with descending powers of $\log N$: for any $k\geq 1$,
$$
\int_{2}^N \frac{\left\{N/t \right\}}{\log t} dt = c_0 \frac{N}{\log N} + c_1 \frac{N}{(\log N)^2} + \cdots + c_k \frac{N}{(\log N)^k} + O_k\left( \frac{N}{(\log N)^{k+1}}\right).
$$
I leave the remaining details of the calculations to you, but this roughly shows that you should not hope for an error term better than $O_k\left( \frac{N^2}{(\log N)^k}\right)$ in your asymptotic expansion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I came up with an empirical approximation that works really well for large $N$. I have no idea how to prove it though.

Comment: The Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_omega_function has a similar expansion for the mean value of $\omega$, which can be converted into the above sort of expansion by summation by parts.

Comment: @TerryTao, Thank you Prof. Tao for providing the solution idea. I shall look into the cited paper.

Answer (score 3):

As Prof. Tao suggested, we can estimate $S(n)$ using [Summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts) method. $$S(n)\sim nf(n) - \sum_{k=2}^{n-1}f(k),$$ where $f(n)$ approximates the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\omega(k)$. $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\omega(k) \sim f(n) = n \left[ \log \log n + M + \sum _{k\geq 1}\left(\sum _{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{\gamma_j}{j!} - 1\right)\frac{(k-1)!}{(\log n)^k}\right],$$ where $M$ is the [Meissel-Mertens constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissel%E2%80%93Mertens_constant) and $\gamma_j$s are [Stieltjes constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants).

Let $T(n)=\sum_{m=2}^{n}f(m)$. We can estimate $T(n)$ using [Euler-Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula). $$T(n)\sim \int_{2}^{n}f(x) dx + \frac{1}{2}\left(f(n)+f(2)\right) + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}\left(f^{(2k-1)}(n)-f^{(2k-1)}(2)\right),$$ where $B_k$ is the $k^{th}$ Bernoulli number (with $B_1=\frac{1}{2}$).

Following this approach we get the following estimates (denoted by $\hat{S}(n)$) for $S(n)$ using $5$ terms in the summatory part of $f(.)$.

| $N$ | $S(N)$ | $\hat{S}(N)$ | Percentage error |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $10^3$ | $1104960$ | $1104744.867385$ | $0.019470$ |
| $10^4$ | $124547620$ | $124548871.265378$ | $0.001005$ |
| $10^5$ | $13558020500$ | $13559354294.383795$ | $0.009838$ |
| $10^6$ | $1446379298344$ | $1446466799145.233356$ | $0.006050$ |
| $10^7$ | $152305298038685$ | $152311928057871.725336$ | $0.004353$ |
| $10^8$ | $15895296473923817$ | $15895763172409493.954120$ | $0.002936$ |
| $10^9$ | $1648198262567978862$ | $1648231275071905930.713382$ | $0.002003$ |
| $10^{10}$ | $170070011690546177056$ | $170072396183761800450$ | $0.001402$ |
| $10^{11}$ | $17482087123791069603605$ | $17482264536463768138654$ | $0.001015$ |